# EAGLViewTest crashing at checkForGLExtension

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Been messing around with the EAGLViewTest with in the cocos2d examples and I have come across a problem. I got the basic test working but when i want to add any ccsprites to the layer it crashes on me when it tries [CCConfiguration checkForGLExtension]. i just tried to add sprite as follows

CCSprite *testSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"test.png"];

I am using 1.0.0-rc3 . I seen someone else post about this issue about adding -ObjC to flags for 1.0.0-rc2 but it didnt work for me.

Anyone got any ideas on this?

Thanks

G

Answer (score 0):

Add "-all_load" to OTHER_LDFLAGS of EAGLViewTest target.

[This fix](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/commit/67ec55d930f2273420d05aebe079815f8952b607) works fine with Xcode 4, however Xcode 3 toolchain might need "-all_load" option for linking.

Comment: yeah im using xcode 4 (im still not sure why yet!) but still no luck with it. its been acting up all day though so i may be trying fresh install or going back to xcode 3 for awhile . i already tried the all load flag too but no luck . thanks though